# Не выполняется код при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android

Есть слушатель нажатия, он запускает void

```
     send1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
mm();

                    try {
                        main1();
                    } catch (LoginException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            });
```

Для наглядности я  вывожу тосты, при нажатии, mm() выводит тост а main1() нет.
Код main

```
 String test = textSend.getText().toString();
      Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");



      cipher2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, originalPublicKey);

    byte[] bytes2 = cipher2.doFinal(test.getBytes());

   Cipher decript2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    decript2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,originalPrivateKey);
  byte[] decriptedBytes2 = decript2.doFinal(bytes2);

   for (byte b : decriptedBytes2)kodMess+=(char) b;

     Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "kodMess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Если тост поставить в начале, то он сработает, если в конце, то нет. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Причина - любой `Exception`. Какой именно и на какой строке - смотрите в Logcat

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте также выводить сообщения об ошибках. Например:

```
send1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    mm();
    try {
      main1();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Toast.makeText(
          ChatActivity.this, 
          e.getClass().getName + ": " + e.getMessage(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
  }
});
```